# log4j not logging when using JBOSS_HOME

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, log4j

I am trying to configure the loggin to my web application.

This is where I want my application to put the logs:

```
C:\installs\JBossServer\jboss-6-0\server\default\log\kiche
```

If I do the following in the  log4J.properties, the logs are created fine:

```
log4j.appender.R.File =C:\\installs\\JBossServer\\jboss-6-0\\server\\default\\log\\kiche\\kicheapp.log
```

I have an environment variable

```
JOBSS_HOME=C:\installs\JBossServer\jboss-6-0
```

And when I do like following in the log4J.properties, it not working.

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${JBOSS_HOME}\\server\\default\\log\\kiche\\kicheapp.log
```

Can someone please help me, I want to use JBOSS_HOME, so that its not hardcoded.

I am using JBOSS as a webserver.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Adofo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better is to edit jboss-log4j.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

JBOSS_HOME=C:\\installs\\JBossServer\\jboss-6-0

and also :

JBOSS_HOME=C:/installs/JBossServer/jboss-6-0 (change log4j.appender.R.File accordingly with "/" instead of "\\")

Also, is there a typo in your question or in your variable ? (JBOSS_HOME vs JOBSS_HOME)

Answer (score 0):

`log4J.properties` cannot access the environment variables directly. Instead , you should use java system properties to do the substitution.

Tomcat 's start up script has the [option](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html_single/index.html#Starting_and_Stopping_the_Server-Using_run.sh) `-D<name>[=<value>]` to  set a system property .Please try to start the  tomcat by using `run.sh -DJBOSS_HOME=C:\installs\JBossServer\jboss-6-0`

Comment: hi Ken,
Its a web application, deployed using JBOSS.
how can I make "log4J.properties" in web application to access environment variables?

regards

Comment: When start the JBoss , `run.sh -D<name>[=<value>]` can set the system property .So you can try `run.sh -DJBOSS_HOME=C:\installs\JBossServer\jboss-6-0`